# Django admin - how to retrieve original value from DB

Tags: python, django

When I click the save button in the Admin of Django, and try to see value of `isActive` checkbox in DB, I receive the new value from current form and not from DB.

For example:

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
employeeList = User.objects.all()
for e in employeeList:
    if (e.username == currUser):
        isAct = e.is_active
```

The `is_active` value that is given is the one currently in GUI and not the one saved at the moment in DB.
Note that I haven't yet updated DB.

Answer (score 1):

How can you be sure you are not saving that value to database?

When you click the save button, the instance is updated in database.

For testing queries and see directly the values in the database i recommend you to use [shell_plus](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: I can be sure because looking at the database, this value hadn't changed yet. Also, when reloading page, the value is the same as the original one. No change has been made.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original data via **obj.pk**

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
  original_obj = User.objects.get(obj.pk)
```

Comment: I tried that and for some reason I receive the changed data, and not the original one. The variable holds the updated data from GUI and not the one that exists in DB.

Comment: @dana You must have saved the data to DB before retrieve it, you can retrieve it in `save_model` function, override it.